# Textarea of TinyMCE(Rich text editor lib) doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am very confuse how I mistake about using TinyMCE.
First I download it from http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php I choose TinyMCE 4.0.3.
When finish download I have folder tinymce_4.0.3 that has folder like tinymce_4.0.3\tinymce\js\tinymce then I copy this folder (js/tinymce) to my website in folder mywebsite.

Atlast I create test.php file with code like this (I cody it from http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open url localhost/mysite/test.php is nothing show.
Does anyone figure out what problem is occur with me?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I am not found any javascript error in console of webdeveloper toolbar add-on in firefox. It make me crazy what problem is. :(

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found problem is because missing plugin.
following code from TinyMCE website, last plugin moxiemanager is not in package free download that why above code can't show anything.

```
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor moxiemanager"
],
```

for solve problem is just remove moxiemanager.

Thanks everyone.